# how to get result from table where there are no values only after joining two tables

Tags: mysql, jsp

```
Statement st=conn.createStatement();
String sql="SELECT a.ID,a.A_TEXT,a.B_TEXT,a.C,a.D_TO_E,a.F_TEXT,a.G,a.INTIME,b.EXIT_TIME FROM tm_A a LEFT JOIN tm_B b ON a.ID=b.ID WHERE EXIT_TIME=''";

ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);

while(rs.next())
    {

    arls.add(rs.getString("ID"));
    arls.add(rs.getString("A_TEXT"));
    arls.add(rs.getString("B_TEXT"));
    arls.add(rs.getString("C"));
    arls.add(rs.getString("D_TO_E"));
    arls.add(rs.getString("F_TEXT"));
    arls.add(rs.getString("G"));
    arls.add(rs.getString("INTIME"));
    arls.add(rs.getString("EXIT_TIME"));

    }
```

I have above code in that i want to retreive values from two tables where EXIT_TIME ='null'
but i am getting nothing after executing though there are value in table tm_A
but if i remove where clause then i am getting result and but under EXIT_TIME it displays 'null' and where there are values that are displaying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select a result where a column is `null` you have to use the `is` operator:

```
SELECT a.ID,a.A_TEXT,a.B_TEXT,a.C,a.D_TO_E,a.F_TEXT,a.G,a.INTIME,b.EXIT_TIME 
FROM tm_A a 
LEFT JOIN tm_B b ON a.ID=b.ID 
WHERE EXIT_TIME is null
```

Comparison with `null` will always result to `unknown`. That is why you need the `is` operator instead of `=`

using `EXIT_TIME=''` would compare `EXIT_TIME` to an empty string but not `null`

If you want all records that are **not** `null` in `EXIT_TIME` you can use

```
WHERE EXIT_TIME is not null
```

### Edit

You can use `case` to avoid `null` in your textboxes:

```
    SELECT a.ID, 
       a.A_TEXT,
       a.B_TEXT,
       a.C,
       a.D_TO_E,
       a.F_TEXT,
       a.G,
       a.INTIME,
       case when b.EXIT_TIME is null
            then 'NA'
            else b.EXIT_TIME
       end as EXIT_TIME
FROM tm_A a 
LEFT JOIN tm_B b ON a.ID=b.ID
```

Comment: but if i don't want to diaplay 'null' in text box ,means if i want display NA then

Comment: I thanked you for your answer but using your edited answer solution i am getting all values from table where entry for EXIT_TIME is present and where it is not. if I use 'WHERE EXIT_TIME is null' then i am getting only those values where entry for EXIT_TIME is not present but it displays 'null' in text box I want to display 'NA' there.

Comment: See this [SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d064/3). It should display `NA` in your textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Just say

`WHERE EXIT_TIME is null`

instead of

`WHERE EXIT_TIME=''`

Hope it helps you...